# What is the regex(format) behind the phone number detector available in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, phone-number, nsdatadetector

```
NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber.rawValue)
```

I applied this code for phone number validation.
Does anyone know for what phone number convention is this applicable (eg: E.164, Europe, US) or the regex behind it?

I didn't find anything in the Apple documentation and I need this in order to apply the same phone number validation also for Android.

Comment: I guess it's quite smart of Apple to only describe this feature broadly. This way they can improve their implementation over time without breaking any previous specifications. ;)

Comment: the best way to find out will be to write some code which autogenerates phone numbers and tests it.